# Unable to build .Net core 3.0 project for linux on windows machine using VS Code

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, build, asp.net-core-webapi

I have windows 7 64 bit machine. Following is the output of `dotnet --info`

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.1.7601
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win7-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  7d57652f33

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNe
tCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.
App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.W
indowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Following is my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

When I try to run `dotnet build -r linux-x64` I get the following error

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0+0f4c62fea for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64 (= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64 (= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.linux-x64 (= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'.
  Restore failed in 117.05 ms for C:\Users\viraj\Documents\Projects\MS\SampleWebApi\SampleWebApi.csproj.

Build FAILED.

error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64 (= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64 (= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.linux-x64 (= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'.
    0 Warning(s)
    3 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.76
```

I think I am missing installing runtimes on my windows machine. But I am not sure how to add runtimes for linux on my windows machine. I could not find any documentation.
I ultimately want to deploy this on a linux machine.

Comment: Not sure if you will be able to build dotnet using linux-x64 on Windows operating system until you try using docker containers. I think you can build successfully using `dotnet build` without using `-r` switch.  `RuntimeIdentifier` will only be helpful when you need to publish the application as a self contained package. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#additions

Comment: Primary check, looking at the `NuGet` errors, do you have appropriate package source(s) added under your NuGet config?

Comment: @SaiGummaluri you were right. I am using VS code. It doesn't automatically add nuget org package source.Once I added it started working.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I want to publish a self contained package.

Comment: @VirajPangam, glad it helped fix the issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you are not using the windows paths

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because VS code doesn't automatically pull from nuget.org.

Creating a Nuget.config file and adding nuget.org package source fixed it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
</packageSources>
</configuration>
```